# How to name WordPress template for category AND custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm using categories for species for a nature photography site and a custom taxonomy called location to capture where the photos were taken.

I'd like to load a different template when the category is "flora" and the location is "south-america", so I named my template category-flora-taxonomy-location-south-africa.php.

If I go to http://mywebsite/species/flora/location/south-africa/ the correct post is loaded, but not my template. I did flush re-write rules by saving permalinks. I also tried the following filenames for my template, same result:

```
category-flora-taxonomy-location-south-africa.php
category-flora-taxonomy_location-south-africa.php
taxonomy-location-south-africa-category-flora.php
taxonomy-location-south-africa_category-flora.php
```

Does WordPress support mixing categories and custom taxonomies in template names like this or do I have to explicitly load my template? If this is the case, what's the method to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That rule is not a part of WP, but we can be build it...

In functions.php add and tweak this:

```
add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', function ( $template )
{

    // get category and term slugs from post object via get_queried_object()

    $custom_template = 'category-{$category}-taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term}.php';
    $locate_template = locate_template( $custom_template );

    if ( !$locate_template )
        return $template;

    return $template = $locate_template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For archive pages, get_queried_object() only gets the category, but not the custom taxonomy I also have to check. So I'm using the globals $category_name and $location instead. Here is the modified code:

```
add_filter('taxonomy_template', function( $template ){
    global $category_name, $location;
    if ( ($category_name == "flora") && $location == "south-africa" ) {
        $custom_template = 'category-flora-taxonomy-location-south-africa.php';
        $locate_template = locate_template( $custom_template );
    };
    if ( !$locate_template )
        return $template;

    return $template = $locate_template;
});
```